# extra value form span in DOM in php

Tags: php, html, xml, parsing, dom

the DOM its working fine with me when I extract the `div.####` but, I don't know how to extract the below value?

```
<span data-ng-if="product.specialPrice" class="current-price ng-scope">
    <strong class="ng-binding">الآن 3,363</strong>
    <span class="ng-binding"> ر.س</span>
</span>
```

This how I get the div

```
$html2 = file_get_html("Link");

$e3 = $html2->find('div.titlemaxheight',0);
$e4 = $html2->find('div.price4',0);
```

Comment: Which value do you want to extract?

Answer (score 0):

I’ve not used `file_get_html()` before, but I’m guessing you can do something like:

```
$html2->find(‘span.currentprice’)->find(‘strong’);
```

Comment: no this code its not correct in the file_get_html() i have try it before .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value inside the <strong>, you might do it like this and get the [innertext](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm):

```
$content = $html2->find('.current-price strong', 0);
echo $content->innertext();
```

If you want to get the value inside the <span>, you might do it like this:

```
$content = $html2->find('.current-price span', 0);
echo $content->innertext();
```

Comment: i have try this way before but won't get me the price inside the strong its showing 0 "check this website"   "https://ar-sa.wadi.com/catalog/?q=iphone+8&ref=search"i am testing on it

Comment: Can you check that what you are looking for is present in the `$content`?

Comment: I check the result of $content . It’s showing {{Product.specialPrice | number :0}} there is no price appearing